# Lucene proximity search between sentences

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, proximity

Is there a solution to search the text `"Apple Iphone X"~5` with only the distance 5 between `Apple` and `Iphone X` and not have a distance between `Iphone` and `X`?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I don't believe you can combine phrases such as `"Iphone X"` and the proximity search syntax all combined in one expression. I believe you would need two separate expressions - for example, `"Apple Iphone"~5 AND "Iphone5 X"`. Of course, that may give you some false positives. I'd be happy to see a better way in an answer.